# Why does preload.js return "ERROR: module not found"?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules

Building an electron app and got stuck with an error.
I don't understand why my preload.js doesn't find the 'dnode' nor the 'path' modules, but it does find the 'url' module.

preload.js:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const dnode = require('dnode'); // It breaks here with 'Error: module not found: dnode'

process.once('loaded', () => {
  window.addEventListener('message', event => {
    const message = event.data;

    if (message.myTypeField === 'handler') {
      // TO-DO
    }

  });
});
```

main.js

```
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const {app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, './preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: false,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol:'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

});
```

My main.js finds the 'path' and 'dnode' modules tho, I've tried changing preload.js to the root directory of the project next to the node_modules folder and It didn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's because you're sandboxing your window.

See the docs ([original on web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210308072550/https://electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option), [current](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox#preload-scripts)):

> With this option enabled, the renderer must communicate via IPC to the main process in order to access node APIs.
>
> ...
>
> A sandboxed renderer doesn't have a Node.js environment running and doesn't expose Node.js JavaScript APIs to client code. The only exception is the preload script, which has access to a **subset of the Electron renderer API**.

If you truly need your renderer process to be sandboxed, then you must instead `require` `ipcRenderer` and use its `send` function to communicate to the main process that can then require all your fancy node modules and send some response back through your preload.

Comment: That's exactly what was happening, I really want to max security so I'll stick with sandbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

if after setting contextIsolation:true,the problem still persist then set the **sandbox: false** option on your **BrowserWindow** to access Node APIs in your preload.

Answer (score -1):

you should set nodeIntegration as true:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    nodeIntegration: true, // like here
    webSecurity: false
  },
});
```

Comment: This isn't good practice as allowing nodeIntegration will introduce an attack vector to the application (as this allows any website loaded through the application to execute javascript)