# Cannot add PouchDB in electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuejs3, pouchdb, quasar-framework

I am using `quasar`**+**`electron` to write a native app through vue.js

Whenever I try to import PouchDB in my electron's preload, I get:
*Error: module not found: pouchdb/dist/pouchdb*

I have installed and tried both `PouchDB` as mentioned [here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/setup-pouchdb.html#typescript) and `pouchdb-browser`, but none work:

I have tried adding pouchdb in my preload with the follwoing ways, and NONE does work:

```
// import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser';
// import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
// import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser';
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
// import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb/dist/pouchdb';
// const PouchDB = require('pouchdb-browser');
// import sampleModule = require('pouchdb');
```

I have followed the guidelines for `TypeScript`, like `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` and `$ npm install pouchdb @types/pouchdb` but still that doesn't solve the problem :S

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653223/why-does-preload-js-return-error-module-not-found